# Type of container used for washing

Tags: vocabulary

What do we call the thing in the image that contains water and has a spout? According to my knowledge this is used in South Asia, usually in toilets for the washing purpose. I've also found that it used to be used for ablution too, before people went to worship in that region when there was no proper water supply system.

Is this a:

a. jug

b. pitcher

c. spouted vessel

d. ewer

e. OR WHAT?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In English it's a borrowed word from Hindi/Urdu: "lota".

Comment: I've never heard it before. It is present in [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/lota) (you might want to add a link to a dictionary).

Comment: @ Wistful But  that's not the standard word I think. I need to know the English word, the standard English, British or American.

Comment: @BadZen a loan word I think you mean, it may be BUT for a non-native to Urdu/Hindi what it is? coz a non-native to Urdu/Hindi won't understand the word you've mentioned.

Comment: That exact type of vessel is particular to India, which is why we don't have a standard word for it elsewhere other then the loan word from Hindi _lota_. Before piped water became universal, _ewer_ was used for a large jug containing clean water ready for use. Nowadays we would just say _water jug_. _Vessel_ is a general word for a container for liquid.

Comment: You might want to capitalize LOTA, because IOTA is something completely different in English.

Comment: A "loan word" is a word that originated in a different language, but has become a standard word of a second language. For example "cognac", "mesa", and "espresso" are examples of loan words.  While it's true that most American English speakers probably don't know what a lota is, that doesn't mean it's not an English word.  There is not another word for it, so far as I am aware.  You could say "jug" as suggested above, but that would not communicate that it was this specific personal hygiene item..  This would be similar to describing dental floss as "string".

Comment: @Davo I'm confident the difference between an 'i' and an 'l' is very clear.

Comment: @KateBunting  I'm certain "lota" is the word that is commonly used to describe this object, and not "water jug", however, if you happen to have one in your house - or are in a house which has one.

Comment: @BadZen I was suggesting that _water jug_ was the usual term for a ewer, not a lota. Not being Indian, I don't have a lota in my house.

Comment: @BadZen Where did you get this definition from? I found here [https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/loanword] this, "a word taken from one language and used in another:"

Answer (score 0):

That is a jug.

A pitcher would probably not have a spout and you would just pour liquid out over the lip.

Spouted vessel sounds very technical. Obviously it is a vessel, and it is pouted, but I do not think anyone would call it that. i imagine an archaeologist might classify finds into the category spouted vessel to include a variety of objects.

A ewer is old fashioned now. It would have come in a set with a large bowl. You would use the ewer to transport the water and then fill the bowl from it to wash yourself in the bowl. This is probably the nearest in terms of functionality to the object you show but it is a quite old fashioned concept now we have piped water. I suspect many young people would have no idea what a ewer was.